# Combine 2 .gz files in linux based on a column with two difference names

Tags: linux

I a new to Unix so please bear with me as I try to provide the most accurate and concise information for this question.

I have file1.gz whose first couple of rows looks like this

```
MarkerName        Allele1   Allele2  Effect  StdErr     Log
chr11:12345:A:G             a        g        -0.00067  0.025   
chr3:812345:T:C             a        g        -0.00067  0.025   
chr13:32345:T:TACC          a        g        -0.00067  0.025   
chr15:62345:G:A             a        g        -0.00067  0.025   
chr2:412345:T:G             a        g        -0.00067  0.025
```

I have file2.gz whose first couple of rows looks like this

```
#CHROM                      ID       REF       
chr11:12345:A:G             A        A         
chr3:812345:T:C             G        G           
chr13:32345:T:TACC          C        G           
chr15:62345:G:A             G        G           
chr2:512345:G:T             A        A
```

I would love to merge these two .gz files so that the new file only has the same MarkerName/#CHROM to generate file3.gz whose first couple rows would look like this

```
MarkerName        Allele1   Allele2  Effect  StdErr     Log    ID   REF
chr11:12345:A:G             a        g        -0.00067  0.025   A    A
chr3:812345:T:C             a        g        -0.00067  0.025   G    G
chr13:32345:T:TACC          a        g        -0.00067  0.025   C    G
chr15:62345:G:A             a        g        -0.00067  0.025   C    G
```

In R I would just

```
file2.gz <- file2.gz %>% rename(#CHROM = MarkerName)
file3.gz <- inner_join(file1.gz, file2.gz)
write_csv(df, "file3.csv.gz")
```

How would I do this using Unix?
Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: Look up the `join` command in linux. This will do what you need.